# fixed tabbar in shell

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

It is possible to make sure that the (Dashboard / Statistics) tab remains fixed without being modified by the various FlyoutItem choices? thanks

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydF5t.png)

```
 <TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Dasboard">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"
                            Glyph="{StaticResource IconHome}"
                            Color="Black"/>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Route="HomePage"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Statistiche">
        <ShellContent Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>

<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Title="Online Store" Icon="ic_online_store" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="About Us" Icon="ic_about_us" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Contact Us" Icon="ic_contact_us" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Sign In" Icon="ic_login" Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Title="Test1" Icon="ic_online_store" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Test2" Icon="ic_about_us" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `MenuItem` to show the items in the Flyout. And use the `FlyoutItem` to show the tabs in the bottom tabbar without setting the `FlyoutDisplayOptions` property to `AsMultipleItems`.

The `MenuItem` would show the item in flyout and the items in `FlyoutItem` would show in the bottom tabbar.

```
 <MenuItem
    Command="{Binding AboutCommand}"
    Icon="tab_about.png"
    Text="Online Store" />

<FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent Title="Dasboard" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Statistiche" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate _v:AccountPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute("account", typeof(AccountPage));
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    public ICommand AboutCommand => new Command(async () => await NavigatedToAccount());

    async Task NavigatedToAccount()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("account");
        Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: in this way if I press on the menuitem I see the page that changes underneath, but the left menu does not close

Comment: You could set the `FlyoutIsPresented` to false to close the flyout. Check my update.

Comment: Have you tried the `FlyoutIsPresented` property?  Did this help you to close the left menu?

Comment: it works well. thank you